# Flutter : error when i'm trying to parse a Map<String, String>

Tags: json, flutter

i have a factory to convert a json file to a class

```
  Map<String, dynamic>? tokenProperties;

  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  
    return Token(
        tokenProperties: map['properties']
      );
  }
```

i receive in "map" param (keys are dynamics, never the same keys and values.)

[image]

when i want to affect the value `tokenProperties: map['properties']`
i don't why but the quote disappear... see the exception:

[image]

The full class:

```
// Dart imports:
import 'dart:convert';

/// SPDX-License-Identifier: AGPL-3.0-or-later

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final token = tokenFromJson(jsonString);

Token tokenFromJson(String str) => Token.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String tokenToJson(Token data) => jsonEncode(data.toJson());

String tokenToJsonForTxDataContent(Token data) {
  return jsonEncode(data.toJsonForTxDataContent());
}

class Token {
  Token(
      {this.address,
      this.genesis,
      this.name,
      this.id,
      this.supply,
      this.type,
      this.symbol,
      this.tokenProperties});

  String? address;
  String? genesis;
  String? name;
  String? id;
  int? supply;
  String? type;
  String? symbol;
  Map<String, dynamic>? tokenProperties;

  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  
    return Token(
        address: map['address'],
        genesis: map['genesis'],
        name: map['name'],
        id: map['id'],
        supply: map['supply'] == null
            ? null
            : int.tryParse(map['supply'].toString()),
        type: map['type'],
        symbol: map['symbol'],
        tokenProperties: map['properties']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
        'address': address,
        'genesis': genesis,
        'name': name,
        'id': id,
        'supply': supply,
        'type': type,
        'symbol': symbol,
        'properties': tokenProperties,
      };

  Map<String, dynamic> toJsonForTxDataContent() => <String, dynamic>{
        'name': name,
        'supply': supply,
        'type': type,
        'symbol': symbol,
        'properties': tokenProperties,
      };
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` in the question. Is that only in question or in the code too?

Comment: Sorry, I extracted a part of the code to simplify. In my code, the parenthesis exists

Comment: Can you show me the full factory class?

Comment: Full class added

Comment: Your code is still missing `);`. Are you sure this is not the cause? Meanwhile, if you try out with iPhone simulator, you will get error in different format and may be it will point out where it is happening.

Comment: And what do you get in console if you print `map['properties']`? You should check if it is actually follow `Map` format.

And what if you try changing `Map<String, dynamic>? tokenProperties;` to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>? tokenProperties;`

There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: too strange. it works now... i think it was a cache pb because after a flutter clean, it was ok and my code was in a lib declared in the pubspec. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thx for help